# The difference between '' It is ... '' and '' Is does be ... ''

Tags: verbs, tenses, nuance

1

John: Does the fax machine be used any more ?

Mary: Yes, it does be used on occasion.

2

John: Is the fax machine used any more?

Mary: Yes, it is used on occasion.

.

Are these different tenses ?

Can anyone explain these two structures in detail ?

Comment: 'Does be used' is not an expression that would ever be found in standard English. Your second version is the only correct one.

Comment: ... though you might say “Does the fax machine **get** used any more”.

Comment: @KateBunting The ''does be'' structure expresses habitualness and does still be used in many places. I guess it is becoming enveloped by the present simple. i.e. I do be cold. (I am habitually cold) is different to: I am cold. (I am cold now)

Comment: @Derek It’s not used in “many places” – just in Ireland. Outside Ireland, it is completely unknown. It’s really just a transplant of Irish _bíonn_ (as opposed to _tá_), a distinction which does not exist in English indigenously and so was created by the Irish.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "be" with "get" in the first dialog.

John: Does the fax machine be used any more ? Incorrect: Use get vs. be.

Mary: Yes, it does be used on occasion.  Incorrect:  Use get vs. be.

2  //Note: helping verbs (do/does/did) of standard English may be problematic if you are used to speaking another language or dialect//

John: Is the fax machine used any more?   Correct: 
                                          Alt:  Does vs. Is; insert "get" btwn machine and used

Alt: John: Does the fax machine get used anymore?

Mary: Yes, it is used on occasion. Correct:
                                   Alt   does get vs is

Alt: Mary: Yes, it does get used on occasion.

An excellent website for English as Second Language for this topic is here: 
https://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/verbs/to-be-used-to.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with ESL or with _get_. _Does be_ is a valid construction in English, just one that’s limited to a particular group of dialects, namely Irish English.

Comment: Shall I provide my reply in Creole English next time, or in Medieval English?  How far off the Standard English path can we stray here? My answers stand as is.

Comment: Irish English is neither a creole nor a historical form of English. It is no less standard than AmE, BrE, AuE, NZE, etc. Would you have suggested an ESL resource if someone had asked about a specific British construction, or a specifically Australian one? We have many questions here about dialectal peculiarities specific to single dialect areas of the US; this is no difference. To answer your question: as far as we wish. This site is not intended to stick narrowly to any kind of prescriptively ‘standard’ English.

Comment: For brevity sake, I'll make no further comment: Observation: Before making any post, I check the poster's profile. There's nothing that would indicate who they are here, This site: The gamut--from a person from India just learning English to a tenured professor of English, and everything  beyond or between--in a blank user profile.   Next time, I'll skip them.